# ClickOnce -Cannot download the application

Tags: winforms, deployment, clickonce

I deployed an application to an ftp publishing folder. And would like for users to download the file from the ftp location but instead what they see is.  What is the cause of this and how do I fix it? 
[image: Click Once download issue]

Comment: if you click on details, what does the message say?